# how can i run a custom action only in modify mode

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield-2012

I need to run a custom action only in Modify mode. I tried below condition but it is running in both Modify mode as well as in Repair mode.

`Installed AND NOT REMOVE`

I am using Installshield 2012 spring.

Comment: Windows Installer doesn't really have such modes. All it really has is installation, repair, or removal of features and components. So what cases do you mean by "modify" that exclude "repair"?

Comment: If we click an entry in control panel, there is a option called "Change"(My package has Uninstall, Change and Repair optons). If you click on that Change button, installshield wizard window will be opened with 3 check boxes named "Modify", "Repair" and "Remove". I am talking about this "Modify" option. If we select Modify option, we can modify installed features.

Comment: Isn't the "Modify" checkbox tied to a public property? If yes, then you can use that property to condition the execution of your custom action.

Comment: That property tied to _IsMaintenance property.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no explicit "modify mode" condition.
but there are condition for installation and uninstallation,
if you exclude both only modify will be left:

```
Not Installed And NOT REMOVE~="All"
```

btw modify and repair is basically the same

Answer (score 0):

[Flexera's "Common MSI Conditions Cheat Sheet"](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/is-chs-common-msi-conditions.pdf) says:

| Sequencing | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| Modify | `Installed AND NOT REINSTALL AND NOT REMOVE~="ALL"` |